# How to emit latest value with delay from faster original flow?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have 2 flows. First flow updates every 50ms. I have the second flow which is equal to first flow but I want it to produce latest value from original flow every 300ms. I found `debounce` extension for flows but it doesn't work (note from docs):

`Note that the resulting flow does not emit anything as long as the original flow emits items faster than every timeoutMillis milliseconds.`

So when I'm trying to emit value each 300 ms with debounce it doesn't emit at all because original flow is faster than I need. So how can I make something like that:

1. delay 300ms
2. check original flow for latest value
3. emit this value
4. repeat

my flows right now:

```
// fast flow (50ms)
val orientationFlow = merge(_orientationFlow, locationFlow)

val cameraBearingFlow = orientationFlow.debounce(300ms)
```

P.S. this approach doesn't fit because we are delaying value so it's not fresh after 300ms. I need to get the freshest value after 300ms:

```
val cameraBearingFlow = azimuthFlow.onEach { 
        delay(ORIENTATION_UPDATE_DELAY)
        it
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need [`sample`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/sample.html) instead of `debounce`

```
val f = fastFlow.sample(300)
```

Comment: That's just what i need. Somehow I see this extension first time ever :/

Comment: @SoulReaver313 well it is a preview feature! If you don't want to use that, you could also experiment with `conflate` and a `delay` in the collector